# asp.net mvc authorizationfilterattribute thread safe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.authorizationfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.authorizationfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

States

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

Does this mean that the following would not be safe to use as a custom asp.net mvc authorization filter attribute because MyCustomRoles is an instance member?

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    // authorized users
    public string MyCustomRoles { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this attribute is set by the calling code:

```
[MyAuthorizationFilter(MyCustomRoles = "abc")]
```

then this property is safe to be used.

See this [`similar post of mine`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937793/29407) for more detailed explanation of cases where it is not safe.

Comment: It is indeed.  The last couple of comments of yours in your linked post were particularly useful.  Thanks.