# ASP.NET Web API caches action filter attributes across requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

There seems to be some weird behavior in ASP.NET Web API (4.0.30506) that I haven't witnessed before.

What I'm seeing is that the same action filter attribute instance is reused over Web API requests. This is especially a problem in case this attribute gets dependencies injected to it, since those dependencies might be specific to the web request. I'm aware that it's better for attributes to be [passive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/), but my assumption was that action filter attributes where not cached.

I searched for any articles, blog posts or Microsoft change logs that described this and the reason behind this, but I couldn't find a single thing. That makes me wonder whether there is something wrong with my configuration that makes this happening. Thing is however, that I'm able to reproduce this issue in a new and empty Visual Studio 2012 Web API project.

What I did was create a new empty project using the *Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application* project with the "Web API" template. It comes with the Web API 4.0.20710.0 NuGet package. After that I added the following attribute:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{id}")]
public class TestFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute {
    private static readonly List<int> used = new List<int>();

    private static int counter;
    private readonly int id;

    public TestFilterAttribute() {
        this.id = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        // Just for testing: I would expect this line never to throw, but it does.
        if (used.Contains(this.id)) throw new Exception("WAT?");
        used.Add(this.id);
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And I add this attribute to the `ValuesController` (part of the default template):

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController {
    // GET api/values
    [TestFilterAttribute]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now when I start the project, go to the /api/values in the browser and refresh that page a few times, the "WAT?" exception is thrown.

Is this normal behavior of Web API and if so, what's the reasoning about this? Or Did I miss some memo about this change somewhere? Does this make Web API attributes extra unsuited for doing dependency injection? Or am I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: As far as I remember, that was huge change for me when coming from asp.net mvc 2.0 to 3.0 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8937793/1679310. And I would say that exactly the same applies to API coming later...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Web API* is built on top of *MVC*, thus it uses a lot of it's functionality.

Attribute instance re-usability is part of the aggressive caching introduced by *MVC 3*. This means that the same `Attribute` instance will most likely be used with all the `Actions` it is applied on. *MVC* pipeline will do it's best at trying to treat your `Attribute` class like a `Singleton`.

Because the same `Attribute` *instance* is reused, it's *Constructor* is not called and `id` is not incremented. If, for example, you increment `id` inside `OnActionExecuting`, all will work well.

You can still do everything you want with your `Attribute`. You only need to keep in mind that you are not guaranteed to always get a new *instance* created. The *constructor* shouldn't contain anything but initial initialization.

```
public TestFilterAttribute() {
    // Instance will be reused thus this will not be called for each Action
}

public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
    // Called on each Action
}
```

Comment: You cannot do everything you want with your attribute. Specifically, due to this caching, you cannot properly use dependency injection of request scoped dependencies. A common case broken by this caching is injection of EF context in authentication filters.

Comment: Also as a result you can not have ANY state in ActionFilter, because the same object WILL be reused across different requests (so it is really a singleton and not a pool of objects)

Comment: If you need to pass some value from `OnActionExecuting` to `OnActionExecuted` you can use `actionContext.Request.Properties.Add` method and then read from that  collection