# Configuring DI container for global filters with services in their constructors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a site using SimpleInjector and MVC, and I'm trying to determine where I'm going wrong architecturally.

I have my DI container being set up:

```
public static class DependencyConfig
{
    private static Container Container { get; set; }

    public static void RegisterDependencies(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
          *snip*

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters, Container);
    }
}
```

And my RegisterGlobalFilters looks like this:

```
public static class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Container container)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

        filters.Add(container.GetInstance<OrderItemCountActionFilterAttribute>());

        if (container.GetInstance<ISiteConfiguration>().ConfiguredForExternalOrders)
        {
            filters.Add(container.GetInstance<StoreGeolocationActionFilterAttribute>());
        }

        filters.Add(container.GetInstance<StoreNameActionFilterAttribute>());
    }
}
```

The store can take orders (through this website) at in-store kiosks or online from home. External orders would need to geolocate to display information to the customer regarding their closest store. But this means I have to use the container as a service locator in my global filters, which means I have to hide the call to the global filters in my DI container. This all seems to me like an anti-pattern or that there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of discussion with a system architect, we came to the (embarrassingly simple) conclusion that the best answer for our architecture would be to create two Register functions in our DI container - one called RegisterCorporateWebSiteDependencies() and another RegisterStoreWebsiteDependencies().

The natural extension of that is to also have 2 global filter configs called after dependency composition, (again) one for RegisterCorporateGlobalFilters() and one for RegisterStoreGlobalFilters().

This results in one overall if statement running the registers ex:

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsCorporate"]))
{
    DependencyConfig.RegisterCorporateWebSiteDependencies(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
else
{
    DependencyConfig.RegisterStoreWebSiteDependencies(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

Which is much more straightforward, and removes the logic from the other locations where it can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real issue with the way you are configuring the container and calling the container to resolve the `Filter` instances, as long as all of this work is being done in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

The underlying problem as I see it is using `Attributes` in manner they were not intended to be used. Useful reads on this subject are [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven)'s post on [Dependency Injection in Attributes: don’t do it!](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98) and [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann)'s post on [Passive Attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/). If you were to follow the suggestion in these posts I think you'd find you end up with code you are much happier with.

Also see this recent question raised by Steven [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646196/asp-net-web-api-caches-action-filter-attributes-across-requests) regarding the singleton nature of MVC attributes.

Comment: I read Ploeh blog I just missed that entry completely, but I can't seem to determine how to implement it for MVC and global filters.

As an aside, I'm worried this answer will be flagged as a link-only answer, as there is no non-link text here.

Comment: @CBauer it was just too long for a comment. There's a working example on [Steven's blog](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Comment: @CBauer did you scroll down to the last comment?

Comment: Yes and it only addressed how to add the SimpleInjectorActionFilterProvider , but not the 8+ references to web api that is in the SimpleInjectorActionFilterProvider .

Comment: @CBauer I thought all those types were defined elsewhere in the post?