# Unit of work pattern - where to use?

Tags: nhibernate, design-patterns, ninject, unit-of-work

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and am using the repository and unit of work patterns with NHibernate and Ninject. I looked at a couple examples ([1](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/), [2](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/)) to help implement UoW, and I'm just not sure *where* I should be using the unit of work. Should it be injected within my controllers, and manually call Commit and Rollback in my actions?

Here's some code examples:

Unit of work (interface extends IDisposable and has Session, Commit and Rollback)

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public ISession Session { get; private set; }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (!_transaction.IsActive)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No active transation");
        }

        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_transaction.IsActive)
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Session.IsOpen)
            Session.Close();
    }
}
```

Part of my Ninject module:

```
Bind<IXXXRepository>().To<XXXRepository>().InRequestScope();
Bind<IYYYRepository>().To<YYYRepository>().InRequestScope();
...

Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x => NHibernateHelper.CreateConfiguration(Path.Combine(
            HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath,
            "bin",
            "hibernate.cfg.xml")).BuildSessionFactory()).InSingletonScope();

Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>().Session).InRequestScope();
```

All my repositories inherit from a class that gets an `ISession` injected, and as I said earlier in the post I'm injecting the `IUnitOfWork` into my controllers and calling Commit and Rollback as necessary. Am I doing this right? Should I only be calling Commit when I'm doing updates or deletes, and don't worry about calling it at all for selects? Will that leave a hanging transaction at the end of every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use an [ActionFilter to automatically begin/commit the unit of work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653761/113702) around every request.  This works great for 95% of my actions.  For the few more complex ones I'll inject the UoW and manage it explicitly from either the controller or the service.

I normally just inject the ISession to the UnitOfWork, as well as to the repositories.  There's really no reason a repository should be aware of a unit of work, it shouldn't be touching the transaction at all.

Comment: So the controller is the right place to be dealing with the UoW, then. Should you just have one UoW per request? Also, what happens if neither Commit or Rollback are called during the scope of a request, are you left with a hanging transaction that's waiting forever?

Comment: Well if you use the actionfilter I linked to above, it will make sure every transaction is either committed or rolled back.  Occasionally I'll need to deal with a more complex process that might have multiple phases of commits etc, and in that case I will make the decision to handle the uow in the service or in the controller.  Typically I end up putting it in the service for complex logic like that.

Comment: OK - and what if Commit/Rollback are not called, does the transaction stay open indefinitely?

Comment: I would think it would probably stay open until it got garbage collected, but I'm not sure.  Making sure it gets committed/rolled back explicitly is definitely the preferred method.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. I think I understand better now.