# Sharing a unit of work among many services in .NET 5 with dependency injection which are used in the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653020/sharing-a-unit-of-work-among-many-services-in-asp-net-mvc-3) is the most similar question I found related to my problem, which is the same but in .NET 5 (the one following .NET CORE 3.1).

I'm using microsoft default DI.

I have a unit of work which I configure in Startup.cs with

```
services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

which as far as I read gives an instance of uow for each controller when called.

problem arises when I have a controller that needs to use multiple services, which must be under a single transaction.

Something like

```
[Area("MyArea")]
    [Authorize]
    public class RandomController
    {
        private readonly MainService mainService;
        private readonly Service2 service2;
        private readonly Service3 service3;
        public RandomController(MainService mainService,
            Service2 service2,
            Service3 service3)
        {
            this.mainService = mainService;
            this.service2 = service2;
            this.service3.UnitOfWork = service3;
        }
    }
```

At the moment a service is like:

```
public MainService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, other injected stuff)
```

So, as of now, every service gets his own instance.

This is good until you get more than one service in the same controller.

The thing is now implemented in a BAD way.

I made every service inherit from a base service:

```
public interface IBaseService : IDisposable
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
    public RandomController(MainService mainService,
        Service2 service2,
        Service3 service3)
    {
        this.mainService = mainService;
        this.service2 = service2;
        this.service2.UnitOfWork = service2.UnitOfWork;
        this.service3.UnitOfWork = service3.UnitOfWork;
        this.service3.UnitOfWork = service3.UnitOfWork;
    }
```

and the base service implementation is

```
public class BaseService : IBaseService, IDisposable
{
    public IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork
    {
        get
        {
            return unitOfWork;
        }
        set
        {
            //Dispose old unit of work and sets new one
            this.unitOfWork.Dispose(true);
            this.unitOfWork = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So basically when you do this:

```
this.mainService = mainService;
```

You get an instance of the service, and when you do this

```
this.service2.UnitOfWork = service2.UnitOfWork;
```

the setter disposes the old unit of work and replaces with the new one.
It's bad because it actually instance a unit of work for each service, then disposes it and then replaces it, which is a big waste of resources.

Now, how to do this better?

The only way I can think of it's kinda of a UnitOfWork factory.

Something like

```
    public static UnitOfWorkFactory()
    {
        public static GetUnitOfWorkInstance()
        {
            public IUnitOfWork GetInstance()
            {
                return (IUnitOfWork)serviceProvider.GetService(IUnitOfWork);
            }
        }
    }
```

So it will do like this

```
    [Area("MyArea")]
    [Authorize]
    public class RandomController
    {
        private readonly MainService mainService;
        private readonly Service2 service2;
        private readonly Service3 service3;
        public RandomController(MainService mainService,
            Service2 service2,
            Service3 service3)
        {
            this.mainService = mainService;
            this.service2 = service2;
            this.service3.UnitOfWork = service3;
        }
    }
```

So if you call unitofwork it will check if it's null.

when you get the unitofwork from the service it will do

```
 private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork {
            get 
            {
                return unitOfWork ?? UnitOfWorkFactory.GetUnitOfWorkInstance();
            }
            set
            {
                UnitOfWork = value;
            } 
        }
```

Any advice?

Comment: Register IUnitOfWork as a scoped service (`services.AddScoped`) then when you inject it, it will be shared among all classes for the duration of request (i.e. other classes in the same request scope).

Answer (score 4):

Register your `IUnitOfWork` as a scoped service.

```cs
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

> Scoped objects are the same for each request but different across each request.

ASP.NET Core creates a service scope for each request, meaning it creates classes when they're needed, then disposes them when the request finishes processing.

This will in effect turn your scoped classes into "singleton"s throughout the duration of the request. Whenever you inject an `IUnitOfWork` in any class (that is registered as scoped or transient), you'll get the same instance.

Comment: This is a nice answer.